# How to get specific value using node js

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, nodes

How to extract the property `name` from the object returned from `findAll()`
as I want all the names which are present inside my database but getting `undefined` value

```
function checkDoc(childProduct) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Document.findAll({
      raw:true,
      where: {
        product_id: childProduct.id,
      },
    })
      .then((productDoc) => {
        console.log(productDoc);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return reject(
          getFailureResponseJson("Can't be added please try again :) " + err)
        );
      });
  });
}
```

Output from: `console.log(product);`

```
{
id: 01,
name: ABC,
description: demo,
}
{
id: 02,
name: PQR,
description: demo,
}
{
id: 03,
name: XYZ,
description: demo,
}
```

I am doing `console.log(product.name)` but its showing `undefined` - How can I get the name?

Comment: Try 
`console.log(product['name'])`
Or
`console.log(product[0].name)`

Comment: console.log(product[0].name) should work, you're trying to access name of the product array and that is undefined

Comment: @tomichel Yes Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using foreach loop on products:

```
productDoc.forEach((singleProduct) => {
   console.log('Product Name: ', singleProduct.name)
});
```

Or simply:

```
console.log('Product Name: ', productDoc[0].name)
// where '0' is the index of first product
```

You are getting an array of objects, not one single object, maybe.